# Does cloud vision API supports Checkboxes, radio buttons and signatures?

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, signature, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I am trying to extract data from an image which has radio buttons, Checkboxes and digital signature. Proper data is extracted in text format but unable to extract Checkboxes and radiobuttons. I wanted to ask if there is any specific API to detect Checkboxes and radiobuttons. If so, please provide the API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a pertinent question, as I encounter a similar challenge when attempting to utilize Optical Character Recognition (OCR) for extracting content from documents containing checkboxes. According to my [research](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/features-list), the Cloud Vision API does not offer the capability to discern marked or unmarked checkboxes within a document.

To address this issue, there are tools available such as [Checkbox-Detection](https://github.com/LynnHaDo/Checkbox-Detection), an open-source solution that has demonstrated promising results in tackling this challenge. Another tool, [Beyond OCR](https://beyondocr.com), also claims to be effective in resolving checkbox detection challenges.

I hope this information proves beneficial for others facing similar issues.